# How do you make image masks?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

I have a hexagon in my logo, but it's empty. I'd like to insert some random bits of code or hexadecimal digits in the spirit of some internet pics.

Can anyone recommend simple ways to insert some code in hexagon shape? My intent is to represent our business is dealing with code–related tasks.

Something like:

[image: example]

This is merely a rough sketch, sorry! By the way, how do I make a hexagon in Photoshop? I managed to draw only a pentagon.

I want the image to be very simple.

Comment: Your question seems to be about making a hexagon shape, but the title is about image masks. Please either reword your title, or adjust your question to make them coherent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Photoshop:

- Select the Custom Shape tool (it's nested with the rectangle and ellipse shape tools).
- In the control panel click the shape dropdown, and in the panel that shows up open the flyout menu in the top right corner. Choose "Shapes" from that menu and "Append" from the dialog. This will add a number of shapes to the list. Select the solid hexagon shape.
- Press D then X to make white your foreground color (or choose some other color for the hexagon).
- Draw out the solid hexagon to the size you want. Hold down Shift to constrain the proportions.
- Press X to make black the foreground color (or select the color you want for the text).
- Using the Text tool, drag out a box that's somewhat larger than the hexagon. Fill it with "code".
- Hover your mouse over the dividing line between the Shape layer and the Text layer, holding down Option or Alt depending on your platform. When you see the cursor change shape, click once to make the Shape layer a clipping mask for the Text layer.
- Delete the background layer by dragging its icon to the trash in the Layers panel.
- Save, then Save As in Photoshop PDF and/or EPS format.

This gives you a hex-shaped logo filled with text on a transparent background. It's a vector graphic, so it will scale infinitely.

For use in print, open your original PSD and Save As "Photoshop PDF" but select the PDF/X-1a preset.

Comment: You could also choose the `Polygon tool` from the shape tools stack and input `6` to the `Sides` input box in the toolbar to draw a hexagon.

Answer (score 0):

You'd typically use a mask for this. Are you using any specific software? With vector illustration programs, you'd typically draw a hexagon using the built-in shape tool. You'd then place that on top of the photo of your choice. Select them both and then use some form of an 'apply mask' command.